# Java Scrollpanel resize

Tags: java, swing, scroll

I stared little project of mine.

I have a form filled with buttons. The buttons (Example#) are added during runtime based on the provided resource. See example below:
[image: On startup]

The underlying JFrame has GridBox layout. The first row is what you see,

```
button|button|textbox|button|button
```

the second row is simple JScrollPane with GridWidth and GridHeight set to "remainder", effectively that should fill rest of the window safe from the slight padding I added to the right.

This JScrollPane contains another JPanel without any preset layout and I fill it with the controls (Buttons Example#0 through #9 here) by absolute values. When I shrink the window, the panel correctly adds scrollbars allowing me to scroll through these 9. See below:

[image]

Unfortunately, when I add manually another Example, the scrollbars fail to appear. The button is half out-of boundaries of the window, but I cannot scroll to it. EDIT: Actually, all Examples above these 10 does not display correctly. No matter if they have been created along these 10 or added later in runtime or by myself. See:

[image]

I suspect that there are some fixed boundaries for either the scroll pane or for the panel that is inside the scroll pane, but I can't seem to find, where is the problem and what should I do to make the program work correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Form Code (stripped of unnecessary handlers and irrelevant methods)

if you see TestCommonsButton, it is a class that extends standard JButton only adding a TestSuite type property to it. By all means and purposes behaves as standard JButton

```
package forms;

import java.awt.Container;
import model.ModelConstants;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import model.*;

public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainFrame
     */
    public MainFrame() {

        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    backBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    runBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    headerTf = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    addBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    detailsButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    java.awt.GridBagLayout layout = new java.awt.GridBagLayout();
    layout.columnWidths = new int[] {0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0};
    layout.rowHeights = new int[] {0, 15, 0};
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

    backBtn.setText("Back");
    backBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            backBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    getContentPane().add(backBtn, gridBagConstraints);

    runBtn.setText("Run");
    runBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            runBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    getContentPane().add(runBtn, gridBagConstraints);

    headerTf.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            headerTfActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 4;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 500;
    gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
    getContentPane().add(headerTf, gridBagConstraints);

    addBtn.setText("Add");
    addBtn.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            addBtnMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 8;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 0, 10);
    getContentPane().add(addBtn, gridBagConstraints);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
    mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 889, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 506, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(mainPanel);

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gridBagConstraints.gridheight = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 7;
    gridBagConstraints.ipady = 200;
    gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
    gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
    gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 0, 10);
    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2, gridBagConstraints);

    detailsButton.setText("Details");
    detailsButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            detailsButtonMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 6;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
    getContentPane().add(detailsButton, gridBagConstraints);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        



private void addBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    if (currentlySelected == null) {
        System.out.println("Adding Test Suite.");
        TestSuite ts = new TestSuite("Name Please");
        testSuites.add(ts);
        TestCommonButton tcb = new TestCommonButton(ts);
        mainPanel.add(tcb);
        new TestCommonsDetailsForm(ts).setVisible(true);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Attempting to add Test level" + (currentlySelected.getDepth() + 1));
    }
}                                   

private void initTestSuites() {
    clearFrameButtons();
    headerTf.setText("Test Suites");
    headerTf.setEditable(false);
    int leftBound = ModelConstants.INIT_LEFT; //some padding
    int upperBound = ModelConstants.INIT_TOP; //some padding
    boolean top = true;
    for (TestSuite tc : testSuites) {
        TestCommonButton jb = new TestCommonButton(tc, tc.name);
        jb.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                TestSuiteButtonMouseClicked(evt);
            }

        });
        mainPanel.add(jb);
        this.testCommonsButtons.add(jb);
        jb.setBounds(leftBound, upperBound, ModelConstants.TEST_SUITE_WIDTH, ModelConstants.TEST_SUITE_HEIGHT);
        if (top) {//we put button to top row, now put one below.
            upperBound += ModelConstants.TEST_SUITE_HEIGHT + ModelConstants.Y_MARGIN_BETWEEN_TESTS;
        }
        if (!top) {//we put button to bottom row. Return to top row and shift right.
            upperBound = ModelConstants.INIT_TOP;
            leftBound += ModelConstants.TEST_SUITE_WIDTH + ModelConstants.X_MARGIN_BETWEEN_TESTS;
        }

        top = !top;
    }

    revalidate();
    repaint();
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Metal look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Metal (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Metal".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    //Load TestSuites
    //TestingPurposes, replace with parser later.
    List<TestSuite> tss = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tss.add(new TestSuite("Example#" + i));
    }

    //---------
    for (TestSuite ts : tss) {
        frame.testSuites.add(ts);
    }

    frame.initTestSuites();

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}

private List<TestCommonButton> testCommonsButtons = new ArrayList<>();
private List<TestSuite> testSuites = new ArrayList<>();
private TestCommons currentlySelected = null;

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton addBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton backBtn;
private javax.swing.JButton detailsButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField headerTf;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton runBtn;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Please provide your code in form of [mcve], so we can understand what's wrong.

Comment: ye, sorry I missed that. Code added.

Answer (score 1):

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
```

Your mainPanel uses a GroupLayout. GroupLayout is one of the most complicated layout manager and is generally only used by IDEs as it requires you to set vertical and horizontal constraints.

In your code you use:

```
mainPanel.add(tcb);
```

without any constraints so the layout manager doesn't work correctly.

I have never used GroupLayout because the constraints are too complex for me. So I suggest you don't generate your form using the IDE. Instead create your form manually so you are in control of the layout manager used and then you can use the appropriate layout manager (or nested panels using different layout managers) for your requirement.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

There tutorial does have an example of using a GroupLayout if you want to take the time to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Without a code example (see the comment of Sergiy Medvynskyy) one cannot be absolutely sure, but I think invalidating the ScrollPane, the panel inside it or both (you just need to try it out) after adding the button might solve the problem. Just call `yourScrollPane.invalidate()` and/or `yourPanel.invalidate()` after the button is added and report if it worked out.

Comment: Either Invalidating or Revalidating does not seem to be doing anything. I was already revalidating the root JFrame though.

Comment: You could try `jScrollPane2.repaint()` after an invalidation. But make sure you add the code in `addButtonMouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)`, not in `initTestSuites()`, were your current invoke to that method is.

Comment: Still does not work. Although through trial and error I realized this is not a problem of "Newly added Examples", but rather ALL examples above those first 10 suffer the same problem, even if loaded on startup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was after all in boundaries of the `JPanel mainPanel`. Despite being able to be stretched and shrank, the underlying JScrollPane always treated it as it was exactly "preferred size" wide/tall (that was set in initComponents().

To counter this, I have added the following code to recalculate the necessary size right before revalidate() and repaint() methods in the init method.

```
GroupLayout gl = (GroupLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, leftBound, Short.MAX_VALUE));
gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, upperBound, Short.MAX_VALUE));
```

Because it always creates new and new instances of `ParallelGroup`, it is probably not the most efficient way to achieve this functionality, but it works as needed.